API Gateway Caching not working , request still going to backend
I am trying to enable API gateway caching but its not caching my requests.
So Basically I have 2 path /servicename/test/* and /servicename/abctest/* . these need to be cached. I added these 2 paths under my stage in the API gateway. I have enabled provioned cache ( 0.5 GB)  on stage and default method caching is inactive. after that, I added a GET method under my API paths and enabled method level caching for both the GET request. But it's not caching my requests. The requests are still going to my backend application. I am not seeing anything on the cache hit or miss.
I tried the integration setting with HTTP and VPC link . in both cases I provide my load balancer endpoint/servicename/ . SO that it reaches correct target group.

Can you confirm that caching is enabled for the specific methods (GET requests for /servicename/test/* and /servicename/abctest/*)? Method-level caching must be explicitly enabled even if you've enabled stage-level caching.
